# How to set ignoreNulls flag for first function in agg with map of columns and aggregate functions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have around 20-25 list of columns from conf file and have to aggregate first Notnull value. I tried the function to pass the column list and agg expr from reading the conf file.
I was able to get first function but couldn't find how to specify first with `ignoreNull` value as true.

The code that I tried is

```
def groupAndAggregate(df: DataFrame,  cols: List[String] , aggregateFun: Map[String, String]): DataFrame = {
    df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).agg(aggregateFun)
}

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (0,  null, "1"),
  (1, "2", "2"),
  (0, "3", "3"),
  (0, "4", "4"),
  (1, "5", "5"),
  (1, "6", "6"),
  (1, "7", "7")
)).toDF("grp", "col1", "col2")


//first
groupAndAggregate(df,  List("grp"), Map("col1"-> "first", "col2"-> "COUNT") ).show()

+---+-----------+-----------+
|grp|first(col1)|count(col2)|
+---+-----------+-----------+
|  1|          2|          4|
|  0|           |          3|
+---+-----------+-----------+
```

I need to get 3 as a result in place of null.
I am using Spark 2.1.0 and Scala 2.11

Edit 1:

If I use the following function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{first,count}
df.groupBy("grp").agg(first(df("col1"), ignoreNulls = true), count("col2")).show()
```

I get my desired result. Can we pass the `ignoreNulls` `true` for first function in Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to achieve this by creating a list of Columns and passing it to agg function of groupBy. The earlier approach had an issue where i was not able to name the columns as the agg function was not returning me the order of columns in the output DF, i have renamed the columns in the list itself.

```
     import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

     def groupAndAggregate(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
        val list: ListBuffer[Column] = new ListBuffer[Column]()
        try {

          val columnFound = getAggColumns(df) // function to return a Map[String, String]

          val agg_func = columnFound.entrySet().toList.
            foreach(field =>
              list += first(df(columnFound.getOrDefault(field.getKey, "")),ignoreNulls = true).as(field.getKey)
            )

          list += sum(df("col1")).as("watch_time")
          list += count("*").as("frequency")

          val groupColumns = getGroupColumns(df) // function to return a List[String]

          val output = df.groupBy(groupColumns.head, groupColumns.tail: _*).agg(
            list.head, list.tail: _*
          )

          output

        } catch {
          case e: Exception => {
            e.printStackTrace()}
            null
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [na](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@na:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions) operator and [drop](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions@drop(cols:Array%5BString%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) all the `null`s before you do aggregation.

> **na: DataFrameNaFunctions** Returns a DataFrameNaFunctions for working with missing data.
>
> **drop(cols: Array[String]): DataFrame** Returns a new DataFrame that drops rows containing any null or NaN values in the specified columns.

The code would then look as follows:

```
df.na.drop("col1").groupBy(...).agg(first("col1"))
```

That will impact `count` so you'd have to do `count` separately.